# Text into C# array

Tags: c#

I have a text stored the database as below.

```
{
"Date and Time":[false,"All","widgetleftZone","510","338",0,0,0],
"How to Videos":[false,"All","widgetrightZone","510","338",0,0,0],
"My Timesheets And Schedule":[true,"All","widgetrightZone","510","338",0,0,0]
```

}

I need to split the text as below.

```
Date and Time: false,
How to Videos:false,
My Timesheets And Schedule:true
```

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Hello, You are not clear about your output is it complete string or Dictionary with string,bool value or something else. And also you have to show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: The spirit of this site is as follow: State you question in expressive manner and show us what you tried to do. You forgot to supply the last part.

Comment: I have no idea how can i achieve this, but I have tries using Regex.Split(x, "\r\n"); with no luck

Comment: @CoderofCode, it's a string stored in database

Comment: this is called JSON. Use newtonesoft json.net

Comment: @AccessDenied I thought it was JSON too. OP just because you believe it's not JSON doesn't mean you can't treat it like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid json.
You can extract values like in the code below:

```
    var str = "{\"Date and Time\":[false,\"All\",\"widgetleftZone\",\"510\",\"338\",0,0,0],\"How to Videos\":[false,\"All\",\"widgetrightZone\",\"510\",\"338\",0,0,0],\"My Timesheets And Schedule\":[true,\"All\",\"widgetrightZone\",\"510\",\"338\",0,0,0]}";
    var js = JObject.Parse(str);            
    var values = from child in js.Properties()
                 select new { Key = child.Name, Value = child.Value?[0] };
    foreach (var line in values)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(line.Key);
       Console.WriteLine(line.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like JSON. I suggest using something like https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp to generate a class to help parse it.

```
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var data = Data.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("Date and Time")]
        public DateAndTime[] DateAndTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("How to Videos")]
        public DateAndTime[] HowToVideos { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("My Timesheets And Schedule")]
        public DateAndTime[] MyTimesheetsAndSchedule { get; set; }
    }

    public partial struct DateAndTime
    {
        public bool? Bool;
        public long? Integer;
        public string String;

        public static implicit operator DateAndTime(bool Bool) => new DateAndTime { Bool = Bool };
        public static implicit operator DateAndTime(long Integer) => new DateAndTime { Integer = Integer };
        public static implicit operator DateAndTime(string String) => new DateAndTime { String = String };
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        public static Data FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Data self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = {
                DateAndTimeConverter.Singleton,
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class DateAndTimeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(DateAndTime) || t == typeof(DateAndTime?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Integer:
                    var integerValue = serializer.Deserialize<long>(reader);
                    return new DateAndTime { Integer = integerValue };
                case JsonToken.Boolean:
                    var boolValue = serializer.Deserialize<bool>(reader);
                    return new DateAndTime { Bool = boolValue };
                case JsonToken.String:
                case JsonToken.Date:
                    var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                    return new DateAndTime { String = stringValue };
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type DateAndTime");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var value = (DateAndTime)untypedValue;
            if (value.Integer != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Integer.Value);
                return;
            }
            if (value.Bool != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Bool.Value);
                return;
            }
            if (value.String != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.String);
                return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type DateAndTime");
        }

        public static readonly DateAndTimeConverter Singleton = new DateAndTimeConverter();
    }
}
```

To use the above send in the database string to the `FromJson` method.

```
var newData = Data.FromJson("{
  "Date and Time":[false,"All","widgetleftZone","510","338",0,0,0],
  "How to Videos":[false,"All","widgetrightZone","510","338",0,0,0],
  "My Timesheets And Schedule":[true,"All","widgetrightZone","510","338",0,0,0]
  }"
);
```

Comment: Appreciate your help.